# Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? on rhel 8.3

Tags: docker

I have installed docker on rhel 8.3 from docker binaries by using command /usr/bin/dockerd & .

every month or after 2 months I get Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running? this issue but meanwhile in the background my all containers & services are working only I can't use the docker command. so in a such case, I kill dockerd process & then restart the docker daemon. is there any other solution instead of the killing process? because of this, I go through data loss issue. I also added a user in the docker group, all binaries have 777 permission as well docker.sock file also. please help me with the solution

Comment: my docker version is 20.10.7

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, Docker was working but I couldn't execute Docker commands.

This was because the symlink of the docker.sock was not correct.

The path /var/run/docker.sock points to /Users/user1/.docker/run/docker.sock instead of /Users/admin/.docker/run/docker.sock

To solve the problem I deleted the bad symlink and recreated it correctly.

```
sudo rm /var/run/docker.sock

sudo ln -s /your/path/docker.sock /var/run/docker.sock
```

make sure you change the path in the example by your actual path.

Comment: in my case /var/run/docker.sock same on server

Answer (score 0):

Try to run all your docker commands with prefix sudo, like:

```
sudo docker ps
```

Or try below command to avoid using sudo every time, if you have are running on a Linux system or change commands accordingly

1. Create the docker group

   ```
   sudo groupadd docker
   ```
2. Add your user to the docker group.

   ```
   sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
   ```

Make sure to restart your system once you run these commands.

Comment: hello priyanka thanks for your comments on my question but i have already created group & all users which i have given to members are added in group as well root user & i am using root user.